# Printing the name of an object in Java

Tags: java, object

I have researched, and although this is a really simple issue, I am not sure how to solve it.

The code I have looks like this:

```
public class Playlist {

   public Playlist(String name) {

   }
}
```

Separate files of course:

```
@Test
public void CreatePlaylist(){
    Playlist myPlaylist = new Playlist("Workout Playlist");

}
```

I am trying to print the actual name of this new playlist "workout playlist" but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: Override the `toString()` method !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write **get method** to name or override **toString** method in the class

```
public class Playlist {

   private String name;
    public Playlist (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Playlist [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Print the name using

`System.out.println(playlistObject.getName());`
or

`System.out.println(playlistObject)`.

**I would prefer** setting a getter method over toString() though.

Answer (score 7):

You need to store the name of your playlist in an instance variable. For instance:

```
public class Playlist {
   private final String name;

   public Playlist(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
}
```

Then you can print it with:

```
System.out.println(myPlayList.getName());
```

If you want to make the name mutable, then get rid of the `final` modifier and add a `setName(String)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Playlist {
  private String name;

  public Playlist(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }
}
```

Then to show the name:

```
@Test
public void CreatePlaylist(){
    Playlist myPlaylist = new Playlist("Workout Playlist");
    System.out.println(myPlaylist.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not at all storing the 'name' property in your object. So obviously you can't access name. One way is

```
public class Playlist {

    public String name;

    public Playlist(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Now you should be able to access your attribute from your testcase like this.

```
@Test
public void CreatePlaylist(){
    Playlist myPlaylist = new Playlist("Workout Playlist");
    System.out.println(myPlaylist.name);
}
```